# Matx33d dot product not working in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, dot-product

My `print` function is defined as:

```
void print(std::string matname, cv::Matx33d A) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s = [\n", matname.c_str());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%15.10lf", A(i,j));
        }   
        fprintf(stdout, "\n");
    }   
    fprintf(stdout, "];\n");
}
```

and I have designed a matrix `H` and used it in the following code:

```
print("H", H); 
cv::Matx33d Hinv = H.inv();
print("H^-1", Hinv);

cv::Matx33d HdHinv(H.ddot(Hinv));
print("H*H^-1", HdHinv);

cv::Matx33d HinvdH(Hinv.ddot(H));
print("H^-1*H", HinvdH);
```

However, the output is as follows:

```
H = [
   0.0386192492   0.1756336675   0.0245675072
   0.1756336675   1.3649487597  -0.2727645303
   0.0245675072  -0.2727645303  -0.5635269575
];
H^-1 = [
  45.9140372920  -5.0221718200   4.4325541956
  -5.0221718200   1.2173491959  -0.8081812555
   4.4325541956  -0.8081812555  -1.1901116767
];
H*H^-1 = [
   3.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
];
H^-1*H = [
   3.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
   0.0000000000   0.0000000000   0.0000000000
];
```

The inverse does seem to be working correctly, but why am I getting these values from the dot product? Am I using `ddot` incorrectly? I have tested this dot product in `Matlab` and I get the identity matrix (up to 10 decimals of accuracy), so I believe that `H` and `Hinv` are being generated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dot product" != "Matrix multiplication". In fact, `cv::Matx33d::ddot ()` does not even return a matrix, but a scalar. I haven't tried it, but probably `operator*` will do what you intend -- like this:

```
cv::Matx33d HdHinv = H * Hinv;
```